# Assigning values to parameter of one stored procedure using another stored procedure

Tags: sql-server, stored-procedures

I want to create a stored procedure that will take values in `@table_name`, `@column_name` as `@param1` and `@param2` and assign values to `@TableToBeExecuted` as `abc_@param1_@param2_Queries`.

```
...
EXEC [dbo].[sp_CreateTable]
     @table_name='Career',
     @column_name = 'profession',
     @TableToBeExecuted = 'abc_Career_profession_Queries'  
GO
...
```

I tried in this way but I could not get the value assigned to as desired.

```
...
EXEC [dbo].[sp_CreateTable]
     @table_name='@param1',
     @column_name = '@param2',
     @TableToBeExecuted = 'abc_'+@param1+'_'+@param2+'_Queries'  
GO
...
```

Comment: Which RDBMS is this for? Please add a tag to specify whether you're using `mysql`, `postgresql`, `sql-server`, `oracle` or `db2` - or something else entirely.

Comment: Why does this entire exercise seem like an incredibly bad way of doing things?

Comment: this exercise is just a part of code, don't make judgements based on few code lines. i need answer to accomplish some other task. please try to give answer to my above question  @NotMe

Answer (score 1, accepted):

No need to get as parameter. You should create a local variable in sp.

```
ALTER PROCEDURE [dbo].[sp_CreateTabl]
    @table_name NVARCHAR(MAX),
    @column_name NVARCHAR(MAX)
AS
BEGIN   
    DECLARE @TableToBeExecuted  NVARCHAR(MAX) = 'abc_' + @table_name + '_' + @column_name + '_Queries'
    -- Sp code here..

END
```